# How to make paragraphs of text or lists line up side-by-side

Tags: css, html, nav

In my spare time I've been coding my own homepage in html. I am trying to get my favorite websites to line up on the left side of the page, but it does not seem to be working properly. The text I want in the center column is below the sidebar of website links, and I want them to be parallel. How would I do that and what is wrong with my code?
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <style>
 .outer {
    width: 1410px;
    color: navy;
    background-color: pink;
    border: 2px solid darkblue;
    padding: 5px;
 }
  .b {
    text-align: left;
 }
  .c {
    margin-left: 8cm;
 }

  .s {
    text-align: center;
 }
  </style>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <div class="outer">
      <h1 class="s">Thank you for visiting my webpage!</h1>
    </div>
    <title>My first webpage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="b">
    <h1>My Favorite Websites</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=http://www.youtube.com/>YouTube</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.google.com/>Google</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.reddit.com/>Reddit</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.gamebuino.com/>Gamebuino</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.netflix.com/>Netflix</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.twitch.tv/>Twitch</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.amazon.com/>Amazon</a>
      <li><a href=http://www.ebay.com/>Ebay</a>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <article class="c">
    <h2>The Official Homepage of Ian Witkowski</h2>
    <dl>
      <dt><h3>Ian Witkowski</h3></dt>
      <dd>A cool dude</dd>
    </dl>
    <p>

    Reasons Ian is cool;</p>
    <ul>
      <li>He is nice</li>
      <li>He rides bikes</li>
      <li>He likes computers</li>
      <li>He can code his own website</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Here is a link for my arbitrary code test page;</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="secondpage.htm" target="_blank">Ian2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </article>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: look into `display: inline-block`...

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems with your code:

1. There should not be any `<div>` inside of your `<head>` tag.
2. The `<style>` should be inside of your `<head>` tag.
3. You can add a `float:left` to your `.b` class.
4. I have also closed some `<li>`s and added the quotes around your `href`s.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first webpage</title>
      <style>
     .outer {
        width: 1410px;
        color: navy;
        background-color: pink;
        border: 2px solid darkblue;
        padding: 5px;
     }
      .b {
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
     }
      .c {
        margin-left: 8cm;
     }
    
      .s {
        text-align: center;
     }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="outer">
          <h1 class="s">Thank you for visiting my webpage!</h1>
        </div>
        <nav class="b">
          <h1>My Favorite Websites</h1>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/">YouTube</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.reddit.com/">Reddit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.gamebuino.com/">Gamebuino</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.netflix.com/">Netflix</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/">Twitch</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com/">Amazon</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.ebay.com/">Ebay</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <article class="c">
          <h2>The Official Homepage of Ian Witkowski</h2>
          <dl>
            <dt><h3>Ian Witkowski</h3></dt>
            <dd>A cool dude</dd>
          </dl>
          <p>Reasons Ian is cool;</p>
          <ul>
            <li>He is nice</li>
            <li>He rides bikes</li>
            <li>He likes computers</li>
            <li>He can code his own website</li>
          </ul>
          <p>Here is a link for my arbitrary code test page;</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="secondpage.htm" target="_blank">Ian2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </article>    
      </body>
    </html>
```

An alternate solution would be to use `inline-block`.  That will also enable it to fall into one column on smaller screens.

```css
.outer {
  max-width: 1410px;
  color: navy;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid darkblue;
  padding: 5px;
}
.b {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.c {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.s {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h1 class="s">Thank you for visiting my webpage!</h1>
</div>
<nav class="b">
  <h1>My Favorite Websites</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/">YouTube</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.reddit.com/">Reddit</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.gamebuino.com/">Gamebuino</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.netflix.com/">Netflix</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/">Twitch</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com/">Amazon</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ebay.com/">Ebay</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<article class="c">
  <h2>The Official Homepage of Ian Witkowski</h2>
  <dl>
    <dt><h3>Ian Witkowski</h3></dt>
    <dd>A cool dude</dd>
  </dl>
  <p>Reasons Ian is cool;</p>
  <ul>
    <li>He is nice</li>
    <li>He rides bikes</li>
    <li>He likes computers</li>
    <li>He can code his own website</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Here is a link for my arbitrary code test page;</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="secondpage.htm" target="_blank">Ian2</a></li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot. I know my code has a lot of bugs and stuff, so it was very generous of you to fix those as well as giving me the answer. Thanks again!